# Snowboarding / Skiing - snow gathers on our goggles - what do you do to deal with this problem?

Tags: skiing, snowboarding, snow-goggles

When we are snowboarding / skiing snow gathers on our goggles. What do you do to deal with this problem?

We can use special liquids like 'fog block' - but are they effective in the terms of snow and rain?

Or maybe wipers would solve the problem? :D
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXK1PKL3n20

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is why most snowboarding and skiing gloves these days have a wiper built in. Rain-X and other coatings can help a little, but there appears to be no all purpose solution, so just get a pair of gloves with a wiper, and get used to using it frequently.

Answer (score 4):

I ride a lot and have never seen any gadgets for fixing this. It depends on the snow as well, since the bigger wetter stuff (so cal / washington mountains) tends to be much more of a problem than the bone dry stuff (co / slc mountains).

Worse is that in conditions with lots of snow coming down you may want to wear goretex shell mitts, and regardless you'll have snow all over your hands since.... well... it's snowing.

I wipe my goggles off when I start going down a run with the sleeves of my jacket, and then I stop as often as I need to and rewipe, or do it during a non-technical stuff where I can move my upper body about.

If it's really dumping clumpy snow, it's going to get on your goggles and it's going to limit your visibility, there's not really anyway around that. But hey, it's powder. Keep the nose up, weight the back, and shred.

If you start losing visibility to the point that you're unable to see contours and terrain angles, it might be time to hit the lodge and grab a beer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a purpose-built solution, check out the Skigee (as in ski squeegee). Light, cheap, stores easily in a pocket. If your issue is simply wet snow clumping on the outside of the lense, these work great. Similarly, the Smith snow eraser (a small sponge and chamois combination) or a dry lens cloth will work well for drying off the outside of the lens. Note that these are all less effective if your issue is the inside lens fogging up.

Personally, I favor having several pairs of goggles in my pack for storm days. Being able to swap in a fresh pair and instantly restore visibility is invaluable. Goggles that have interchangeable lenses also work well (and keep the bulk down), but this approach can suffer from the foam itself getting soggy and immediately fogging up a replacement lens.